# How to create a synonym to a different database without a dblink

Tags: database, oracle11g, synonym, dblink, oracle8i

I've two databases, one Oracle 11g and another Oracle 8i. Since they are such different versions, a dblink is not possible. In my application, I've managed to downgrade the driver version to 10g, so it can connect to both databases. The problem is that I really need to have synonyms on the Oracle 8 database refering back to the 11g one, but I can't create a dblink.

Is there anyother way to create synonyms (and grants, of course) to a different database, without a db link? Until now, Google says no.

Comment: Why can't you create a DB link to an 8i database - is that documented somewhere? I don't have one to try but I would have thought that would still work. How are you trying to create it and what error do you get? I'd agree with Google though, you need a link before you can have a synonym.

Comment: Documented, I think we can say yes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200128/oracle-11g-backward-compatibility-with-older-oracle-releases

Comment: I know 11g *drivers* can't access 8i databases, but I'm not sure I've seen it stated anywhere than SQL*Net itself doesn't support it; arguably the 11g DB is a client in this context but it doesn't seem impossible that in a direct DB-to-DB link this would still work. (It may well not work, and if it does, it may not be supported). Have you tried to create and more importantly use a link? Alternatively, do you have another (10g or 9i) database you can use as an intermediary, as a chain of DB links? Ugly, but if you're stuck on 8i...

Comment: No, you're right; doc ID 207303.1 does say that "For database links between different Oracle versions connections must be supported in BOTH directions" in their client/server matrix, so it is indeed documented *8-)

Comment: There are only two possible scenarios, and practically not easy. Either upgrade to newer version or have an older version of Oracle client.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to use an ODBC Oracle Gateway to connect the 8i database via a database link and the gateway listener and 11g ODBC connector to the 11g database, although I have not tried it (no access to 8i any more) and I would expect there to be some additional limitations over a direct link.